# Micronaut, how to send updates to a websocket endpoint? (Java)

Tags: java, websocket, microservices, micronaut

Currently I discover micronauts and regarding [websockets](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#websocket), I am looking for a solution. Let me describe the idea and the issue:

1. A Browser connects to a microservice with a [websocket endpoint](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#websocket)
2. A session-ID may be send to the websocket endpoint to identify the client
3. On a different http request a long term async work has been started (e.g. with a message queue)
4. The process finishes and needs to tell the right websocket endpoint-thread to give this update to the browser.

[image]

- But what would be a good way to tell the correct websocket thread, connected to the browser, an update is available?
- What if there are more than one websocket microservices, called by a balancer? I think then they can not share any "Session" with an http server?
- Can the exact websocket endpoint subscribe to a message service like Kafka?

I just found people asking the same with no answer. But it seems to be a typical issue.

Comment: You can use a Redis pub/sub channel that all websocket microservices subscribe to, and then once a message is received, each websocket endpoint can forward it to the target client based on the session id (you can use `WebSocketBroadcaster` and a `Predicate` on the session id).

Comment: Oh that sounds interesting. Thanks!